# Routing, optional literal in route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want a route which matches "/", "/Home" and "/Home/Index" but not "Home/Other" and not "/Other".

Is there a better way than to have three route table entries? I want something like the defaults mechanism, but only for literals instead of parameters.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller:regex(^(Home)$)}/{action:regex(^(Index)$)}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

This code will catch only `/`, `/Home` and `/Home/Index` route. If you want only avoid catching "Other" in route then replace regex to `^(?!Other).*$`

Comment: I thought there maybe a better way, but regex is fine I guess.